# Run crontab in docker. Django

Tags: python, django, cron

Sorry for my english. I created docker file. For cron task i user this [library](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab), In my local test all work, but now i try use docker and try run cron there.But now i have error

```
no crontab for root
```

My docker file:

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
RUN python manage.py crontab add
RUN python manage.py crontab show
```

My requirements

```
Django==1.11.4
django-filter==1.0.4
djangorestframework
Pillow
django-crontab
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? Typically cron will create a new crontab for the user when showing this warning message.

Comment: Try set `settings.CRONTAB_EXECUTABLE = '/usr/bin/crontab -e'`

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered this problem while moving a Django project to the docker-compose environment.

Here's what worked for me at [Nginx Unit](https://unit.nginx.org/) which is based on Python3.9 (and some Ubuntu distribution):

1. Somewhere in the Dockerfile there must be cron installed and started.

   ```
   apt install cron -y
   ```
2. Then you need to start it with (i'm not sure about this step, at worst nothing will happen).

   ```
   service cron start
   ```
3. Run django crontab

   ```
   python manage.py crontab add
   ```
4. And the last step, which appears **the autor doesn't have** is running

   ```
   service cron restart
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps django-crontab expects the crontab to exist before adding stuff. You can try to create a new crontab for root first.

```
RUN crontab <<< '# new crontab'
RUN python manage.py crontab add
RUN python manage.py crontab show
```